# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Server encountered an internal error without telling the root cause

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-storage, azurite

Locally I have created with azurite a Blob Storage container and I can write/delete files with Storarge Explorer.

This code starts fine but ends after a view seconds with unhandled exception

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace WatchStorage
{
    #region Constructor
    public class WatchStorageFunctions
    {
        private ILogger Logger { get; set; }
       
        public WatchStorageFunctions(ILogger<WatchStorageFunctions> logger)
        {
            this.Logger = logger;
        }
        #endregion

        [FunctionName("TaskWatchWebjobs")]
         public void RunTaskWatchWebjobs([BlobTrigger("azuritstore/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name)
        {
            this.Logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

this is the local.settings.json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

the error message is just

```
[] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000049821116'.
[] An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
[] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
[] Stopping host...
[] Stopping JobHost
[] Job host stopped
[] Host shutdown completed.
```

I am new to this stuff and would like to have a more detailed error message. Is that possible ?
Any further hint is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can see detailed error message in your local debugging. I have created a Azure Blob Trigger on my end and will show you how you can see detailed errors. Please check below:

1. Upload a blob in the container mentioned in your code (it is samples-workitems for me):

[image]

2. Add try-catch and logging statements like below:

[image]

3. Now, you will be able to see the log errors in the VS Console:

[image]

4. For error messages in Hosted Function App, you will be able to see logs on the portal in **Function App > FUNCTION_APP_NAME > FUNCTION_NAME > Code + Test > Logs Pane at the bottom.**

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer unfortunatetly "an error has occured does not say much" right ?edited the question with error output

Comment: Do you have a container named 'azuritstore'?

Comment: Can you install Azurite by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite#clone-build-and-run-azurite-from-the-github-repository? And check it by running this cli command `azurite --silent --location c:\azurite --debug c:\azurite\debug.log`?

Comment: thanks it looked promissing. Unfortunatetly now Visual Studio complains it can not start storage emulator. It shouldn't do that as I have azurite in VS Code or with your command elsewhere. Any hint how to hinder VS 2019 to start azure storage emulator ?

Comment: it was a problem with the Visual Studio Code plugin. Disabling that and running your command did the Trick !